# Pulling a URL from a feed using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, parsing, nokogiri

Let's say I have this in a document:

```
<entry>
  <link rel="replies" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://www.url.com/feeds/1/comments/default" title="Comments"/>
  <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://www.url.com/a_blog_post.html" title="A Blog Post"/>
</entry>

<entry>
  <link rel="replies" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://www.url.com/feeds/2/comments/default" title="Comments"/>
  <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://www.url.com/another_blog_post.html" title="Another Blog Post"/>
</entry>
```

I am trying to use Nokogiri to pull the urls for each of the blog posts, but I am apparently going about it all wrong (I'm new to programming and having trouble understanding nokogiri)

Here's what I have:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

def get_posts(url)
  posts = []
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  doc.css('entry.alternate').each do |e|
    puts e['href']
    posts << e['href']
  end
  return posts
end 

puts "Enter feed url:"
url = gets.chomp
posts = get_posts(url)
puts posts.to_s
```

Any help would be great! I started this little thing to better learn to program, but I'm stuck. My output currently is `[]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CSS selector is wrong, `entry.alternate` would select all entry elements with alternate class (that is something like `<entry class="alternate" />`).

I suppose you want to select all `link` elements that have `rel` attribute with value of `alternate`. CSS selector for this is `link[rel=alternate]`. So change your code like this:

```
doc.css('link[rel=alternate]').each do |e|
  puts e['href']
  posts << e['href']
end
```

You can read more about CSS selectors here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html.

Comment: <3 Thank you sooo much. I understand your answer. Thanks for the link, I'll have to study up on CSS selectors. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try with `doc.xpath "//entry/link[@rel='alternate']"` instead of `doc.css('entry.alternate')`. It works for me.

Comment: So would the whole line be this?:
  doc.css('entry.alternate').each do |e|

Comment: Nop. it would be `doc.xpath("//entry/link[@rel='alternate']").each do |e|`

Comment: Lol, that's what I meant to type in my comment. I put that in my script but was getting a method error. Thank you for your help, however.

Comment: Can you paste the error? I rather use xpath than css selectors since Nokogiri translates css to xpath and then runs it. For example, it creates the xpath `"//link[@rel = 'alternate']"` for the CSS selector above (you can use `Nokogiri::CSS.xpath_for` method for checking it). Translator is pretty fast, translating your CSS selector 100000 times takes less than half a second.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the href attribute of the links, note that you can more simply do:

```
def get_posts(url)
  Nokogiri::XML(open(url))
    .xpath('//link[@rel="alternate"]/@href')
    .map(&:value)
end
```

The XPath above selects not the `link` elements, but the `href` attributes on those elements; the `map` then turns this array of `Nokogiri::XML::Attr` objects into an array of just their values (as strings). Since this is the last expression in the method, the array is the return value.